# Creating Events via API - Unsupported?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

By reading the new API it says that we are no longer allowed to create Facebook Events for our users. Am I reading that correctly? If that is the case, is there a way that individual applications could be manually approved by Facebook?

We are a full service ticket company (we do not resell tickets) for our customers. Our software has always automatically created events for our customers. I understand trying to get rid of the spam events that get created, but for legit events also?

Example Event:
https://www.facebook.com/events/714621851990427/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, you can no longer create Facebook events with the API. There is no way to get it approved for any App.

As you can read in the docs, there is not even a permission you could get approved: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/event#publish

> You cannot create events via the Graph API.

This is part of the upgrade to v2.0 of the API, the removal of v1.0 was introduced on April 30, 2014. You can read more about the different API versions in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: I think that is a horrible decision by Facebook as I think there are some cases that are beneficial in Facebook.Is there any way that we could call a URL that would fill in some of the important information of an event to make it easier for them to create?